# Delete jni local reference table in android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Hi i have developed android app using phonegap and jquery mobile.when i continuously use my app JNI is crashing my app and closed suddenly.

Here is my logcat error:

```
Android : JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
```

Please help me to delete the jni local reference table from android.

Here is the link which i referred to delete the JNI local ref table: https://github.com/aclindsa/jnioverhead

There is an example in the above link and how to delete the jni local reference table from android.I have created .java and .h file like in the link and its not working.Please guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use env->PushLocalFrame(capacity) in the start of the JNI call, and delete it with env->PopLocalFrame(NULL). On the other hand, the phonegap guys should probably fix this in their code. JNI clears the local ref table once the native method exists.